# Can one recite Kiddush and Havdalah by day on the same cup if he forgot Havdalah by night?

Tags: yom-tov, mistakes, kiddush, havdalah

When Yom Tov falls out on Motzaei Shabbos, one recites Kiddush and Havdalah on the same cup of wine at night. If one said Kiddush but forgot until morning to say Havdalah, how should he proceed?

Can he recite the morning Kiddush and Havdalah during the day on the same cup, or not, being that there is no special blessing for Kiddush by day and the Kiddush won’t be noticeable?

Comment: Without a source, https://www.shulchanaruchharav.com/the-law-if-one-did-not-say-havdalah-on-motzei-shabbos/#_ftnref31 says you can do it. 
What is one to do if he forgot to say Havdalah in Kiddush of Yom Tov which falls on Motzei Shabbos?

He is to say Havdalah over wine immediately upon remembering, whether he remembers that night or the next day.[31] If he remembered before the Yom Tov day meal, he is to say Havdalah over a cup of wine and then eat the meal. If one remembered only on Sunday night which is also Yom Tov, then he is to say Havdalah within Kiddush.

Comment: From the MA 299:9 it would seem that it could be done as well since your mentioning Yom tov in the Havdalah https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.299.9?lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel *he is to say Havdalah over a cup of wine and then eat the meal*... it's not clear that means to combine it with kiddush. He might just be saying you have make havdalah before eating the meal.